# Using SQL Queries in Apache Ignite without a database

Tags: sql, postgresql, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite as a distributed cache whose configuration I've generated based on an existing database using the Ignite Web Console--it's a writethrough cache that will periodically persist cached data to the Postgres database.  However, I want to write unit tests in Java for my project, and do not have a reliable test database to use.

Part of what I'm wanting to test are the cache queries I'm occasionally running on my Ignite cache--I wanted to use sql queries to do this.  However, I can't figure out how to preserve the queryEntities from my cache configuration without also having the database.  I tried making a new xml file for test purposes that only configures the caches I need, and only sets the query entities (not the datastore or any db information), but when I run the test I get a "Failed to initialize DB connection" error--even though there is no DB defined in my config.

Is there a way to leverage these query entities without actually connecting the cache to a database?  If not, is there a good way to spin up a postgres database as a part of a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check persistence store configuration and disable that first to have everything in memory.
Next, make sure you are not initializing any DB connection while having your test cache configuration(You already said you looked after this fact).

Comment: I don't have anything in my xml defining a persistence store configuration.  Is there some default value I need to be overriding?

Comment: No,  there is no default for persistence store.  If you are using any plugin for db connection in configured,   that might cause issue.

Comment: There isn't any plugin being set in the config that I can see.  The error looks like this:

"IgniteSQLException: Failed to initialize DB connection: jdbc:h2:"

And then a bunch more stuff.  I'm not telling it to use h2 anywhere, or setting any kind of jdbc driver.  I am trying to set up query fields and indexes, but nothing about a datbase.  So I'm not sure where it's trying to make an h2 connection from.

Comment: This was right--turns out I did have a CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory in some of my beans that needed to be removed.

Comment: Congrats.  There you go.

Answer (score 0):

`cacheCfg.setWriteThrough(false).setReadThrough(false)` should do the trick when defining a cache (note that after cache is started cfg can't be changed)

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.  I didn't have anything set in the config for readthrough or writethrough, but now I've gone in and set them to false in the xml file.  Still seeing the same "failed to initialize DB connection" error message.

Comment: Can you please share whole stack trace?

Comment: I was able to get it to work--I just removed the cacheStoreFactory from the bean and made sure that readThrough and writeThrough were set to false